# Align rows inside cases with rows in next column inside table

Tags: tables, align, cases, aligned

I'm trying to create a table with equations as below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
\hline
cell1 & cell2  \\
\hline
\text{Some text}
\begin{math}
\begin{aligned}
 \begin{dcases}
  \text{Text1} & \boldsymbol{X1} = \boldsymbol{a1}+\boldsymbol{b1}\boldsymbol{Y1} \\
  \text{Text2} & \boldsymbol{X2} = \boldsymbol{a2}+\boldsymbol{b2}\boldsymbol{Y2} \\
  \text{Text3} & \boldsymbol{X3} = \boldsymbol{a3}+\boldsymbol{b3}\boldsymbol{Y3} \\
  \text{Text4} & \boldsymbol{X4} = \boldsymbol{a4}+\boldsymbol{b4}\boldsymbol{Y4}
 \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}
\end{math}
 & 
$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Text5} & \boldsymbol{X5} = \boldsymbol{a5}+\boldsymbol{b5}\boldsymbol{Y5} \\
\text{Text4} & \boldsymbol{X6}=
\begin{aligned}
 \begin{dcases}
  \boldsymbol{a61}+\boldsymbol{b61}\boldsymbol{Y61} \\
  \boldsymbol{a62}+\boldsymbol{b62}\boldsymbol{Y62}
 \end{dcases}
\end{aligned} \\
\text{Text6}  & \boldsymbol{X7} = \boldsymbol{a7}+\boldsymbol{b7}\boldsymbol{Y7} \\
\text{Text7}  & \boldsymbol{X8} = 
\begin{aligned}
 \begin{dcases}
  \boldsymbol{a81}+\boldsymbol{b81}\boldsymbol{Y81}  \\
  \boldsymbol{a82}+\boldsymbol{b82}\boldsymbol{Y82} 
 \end{dcases}
\end{aligned}
\end{array}$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output
[image: output]

Obviously this table looks ugly. What I need is to align the rows inside the bracket so each one corresponds to another from next column; text1 with text5 and so on:
[image: desired_output]

I'm a beginner in latex, can someone help align those texts to beautify the table a bit? and maybe there are better packages to use to automate this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc|cl|}[cell-space-limits=6pt]
\Hline
\Block{1-3}{cell1} & & & \Block{1-2}{cell2}  \\
\Hline
\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=5mm]{}
\Block{4-1}{Some text}
& Text1 & $\boldsymbol{X1} = \boldsymbol{a1}+\boldsymbol{b1}\boldsymbol{Y1}$ 
& Text5 & $\boldsymbol{X5} = \boldsymbol{a5}+\boldsymbol{b5}\boldsymbol{Y5}$ \\
& Text2 & $\boldsymbol{X2} = \boldsymbol{a2}+\boldsymbol{b2}\boldsymbol{Y2}$ 
& Text4 & $\boldsymbol{X6}=
           \begin{aligned}
            \begin{dcases}
             \boldsymbol{a61}+\boldsymbol{b61}\boldsymbol{Y61} \\
             \boldsymbol{a62}+\boldsymbol{b62}\boldsymbol{Y62}
            \end{dcases}
           \end{aligned}$ \\
& Text3 & $\boldsymbol{X3} = \boldsymbol{a3}+\boldsymbol{b3}\boldsymbol{Y3}$ 
& Text6 & $\boldsymbol{X7} = \boldsymbol{a7}+\boldsymbol{b7}\boldsymbol{Y7}$ \\
\RowStyle[cell-space-bottom-limit=5mm]{}
& Text4 & $\boldsymbol{X4} = \boldsymbol{a4}+\boldsymbol{b4}\boldsymbol{Y4}$ 
& Text7 & $\boldsymbol{X8} = 
           \begin{aligned}
            \begin{dcases}
             \boldsymbol{a81}+\boldsymbol{b81}\boldsymbol{Y81}  \\
             \boldsymbol{a82}+\boldsymbol{b82}\boldsymbol{Y82} 
            \end{dcases}
           \end{aligned}$ \\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\lbrace}{2-2}{5-2}{.}[extra-height = -5mm]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The adjustment of the vertical spaces (as demanded by the OP in a comment) is a bit tricky: the commands `\RowStyle[cell-space-top-limit=5mm]{}` and `\RowStyle[cell-space-bottom-limit=5mm]{}` create vertical space and the key `[extra-height = -5mm]` of the command `\SubMatrix` adjusts the size of the brace.

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1 It's such an easy task with `nicematrix`. I think it's time to get familiar with it :)

Comment: Thank you so much :D, but now I have 2 problems: 1) I want to have some margin between { and the horizontal lines, I tried adding vertical space after `\Hline` but only the text was affected while { stayed the same. 2) I added a bit longer equations beside X6 and now the table is clipped on the right so the rightmost part of it is not visible in the page. Can you help please? thanks.

Comment: I have modified my answer for your first question, but I'm sure to understand the second. If you want, you can send me an email: you will find my adress in the documentation of the package `nicematrix`.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to keep things aligned, you probably need to keep everything together As such, make one big table, in which each row contains both groups of expression including.

The big curly left bracket is a little tricky. I guess there is a better solution than mine using e.g. `nicematrix` and I think someone will likely propose that solution but for time being below is what also works.

`\raisebox` reduces vertical dimension of boxes containing "Some text" and the bracket to zero. This way nothing is "pushed" down when their contents is lowered to the point to achieve in the middle alignment. You will need to work out new numbers if you change the content.

`\xmathstrut` is a convenient macro which adds extra vertical space. Without it the last `dcases` would be too close to the bottom rule

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{r@{\;}c@{} r@{\;}>{\(}l<{\)} @{\qquad} r@{\;}>{\(}l<{\)}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{cell1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{cell2} \\
    \midrule
    \raisebox{-2.9\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Some text}
                              & \raisebox{-2.9\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{
                               \(\left\{
                               \rule[-3.75\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{7.5\normalbaselineskip}
                               \right.\)}
    & Text1
    & \boldsymbol{X1} = \boldsymbol{a1}+\boldsymbol{b1}\boldsymbol{Y1}
    & Text5
    & \boldsymbol{X5} = \boldsymbol{a5}+\boldsymbol{b5}\boldsymbol{Y5} \\
    &
    & Text2
    & \boldsymbol{X2} = \boldsymbol{a2}+\boldsymbol{b2}\boldsymbol{Y2}
    & Text4 & \boldsymbol{X6} = \begin{dcases}
                                  \boldsymbol{a61}+\boldsymbol{b61}\boldsymbol{Y61} \\
                                  \boldsymbol{a62}+\boldsymbol{b62}\boldsymbol{Y62}
                                \end{dcases} \\
    &
    & Text3 & \boldsymbol{X3} = \boldsymbol{a3}+\boldsymbol{b3}\boldsymbol{Y3}
    & Text6 & \boldsymbol{X7} = \boldsymbol{a7}+\boldsymbol{b7}\boldsymbol{Y7} \\
    &
    & Text4 & \boldsymbol{X4} = \boldsymbol{a4}+\boldsymbol{b4}\boldsymbol{Y4}
    & Text7 & \boldsymbol{X8} = \begin{dcases}
                                  \boldsymbol{a81}+\boldsymbol{b81}\boldsymbol{Y81}  \\
                                  \boldsymbol{a82}+\boldsymbol{b82}\boldsymbol{Y82} 
                                \end{dcases}\xmathstrut[1.25]{0} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table}\label{tab:table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```